# Why Ember.onerror() not capturing the Assertion Failed error.?

Tags: ember.js

I have a situation in my code where i need to trace the errors in my production.

I used `ember.js` as my framework.

To trace the errors occuring in production i used `Ember.Onerror` which provides me only any functionality error trace.

```
Ember.onerror = function(error) {
  Em.$.ajax('/error-notification', 'POST', {
    stack: error.stack,
    otherInformation: 'exception message'
  });
}
```

But i would like to trace the assertion failed errors for example

**The URL *** didnot match any of the routers in your application*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is really few documentation on Ember about catching errors and assertions errors. In my case, I needed to visualize these exceptions beyond the console in my debug mode, before going into production. So, I went to the Ember project in GitHub and found the specification and implementation for the Ember.onerror(error) {...} and Ember.assert(desc, test) {...} functions and then I just wrote my own version of these functions inside the initialize function of a new adapter (app/initializers folder) that I decided to name errorHandler.

```
Ember.assert = function(desc, test) {
    if (!test) {
        console.log('This is a test to log Assertions!');
        /* your assertion treatment code goes here*/
        throw new Ember.Error("Assertion Failed: " + desc);
    }
}
```

...and by throwing that new Ember.Error(...) you are actually calling:

```
Ember.onerror = function(error) {
    console.log("An error has occurred in ember: " + error.message);
    /* your error treatment code goes here*/
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Ember's build tools strip out the assertion/debug calls, such as `Ember.assert()`, so if you are using the `ember.prod.js` or `ember.min.js` you won't get assertions.

In the [API docs for `Ember.assert()`](http://emberjs.com/api/#method_assert):

> Define an assertion that will throw an exception if the condition is
>   not met. Ember build tools will remove any calls to Ember.assert()
>   when doing a production build. Example:
>
> ```
>     // Test for truthiness
>     Ember.assert('Must pass a valid object', obj);
>     // Fail unconditionally
>     Ember.assert('This code path should never be run')
> ```

Comment: so Ember wont throw any assertion failed errors in production build. thats true for my case too. but my question is if i want to trace out the assertion error. though its thrown or not thrown. i need to keep them track.. so that i could check for downtime happen due to these type of failures. any solution????