# HTMLBars render test

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js

Currently I am building an ember.js component which has 2 modes, display and edit.  When the component is in display mode, it inline renders the template string, which is a property of an associated model.  When in edit mode, the component displays the template string in a content editable.  I had to make the component re-initialize upon mode toggle by putting 2 instances of the component in a template if/else statement.  The following code in my component enables this:

```
`import layoutDefault from '../templates/components/positionable-element-default'`
```

.....

```
  layout:Em.computed(->
    if @.get('layoutComponent.displayMode') 
      Ember.HTMLBars.compile(@.get('regionModel.textContent')) 
    else
      layoutDefault
  )
```

My idea for solving render failing to strip out the { and } characters of the template string and then recompile after alerting the user of the error.

I tried putting the compile function in a try catch but nothing is caught , presumably because its not the compiling that is the problem but rather the rendering.

Upon some research, I found [Why Ember.onerror() not capturing the Assertion Failed error.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255637/why-ember-onerror-not-capturing-the-assertion-failed-error) but it looks like I will never be able to catch assertion errors in production.  Therefore my question is: is possible to ascertain whether or not a template string will render properly or not ?  Or is this kind of functionality outside the scope of ember's capabilities ? Pointers much appreciated :)

Comment: You really *should not* use different templates for one component! Use two components and put common functionality into a mixing! Or use an `{{if}}` block in your templates an may call sub templates.

Answer (score 1):

I'm think you might be able to solve your problem by using the component helper to display a component dynamically, have a look at this [post](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/03/26/emberjs-dynamically-render-components/) for a detailed explanation on how it works etc.

Here is how I recommend you try to solve your problem using the component helper:

```
// components/toggling-component.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  mode: 'display',
  modeComponent: Ember.computed('mode', function(){
    return this.get('mode') + '-mode'
  }),
  actions: {
    setMode(mode){
        this.set('mode', mode) 
    }
  }
})

// templates/components/toggling-component.hbs
Current Mode: {{mode}}<br/>
<button {{action 'setMode' 'display'}}>Toggle Display</button>|
<button {{action 'setMode' 'edit'}}>Toggle Edit</button> 
<hr/>
{{component modeComponent text=model.textContent}}
```

Now, by toggling that mode property, you can load whatever modes you'd like, where a mode will correspond to components like the following two:

```
// templates/components/display-mode.hbs
Display Mode Component: <br/>
{{text}}

// templates/components/edit-mode.hbs
Edit Mode Component: <br/>
{{textarea value=text cols="80" rows="6"}}
```

Here is a [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/14a9f5f3616380cf05da7104410bef92) that demonstrates the complete solution.

Comment: This is a useful alternate approach that helped me with another problem, thanks :)  However, it didn't address the gist of my inquiry, how to catch failed inline template compilation

Comment: Also, because each components needs its own template string based on an associated model, I don't think I can use the modeComponent (because a template with that name has to be already defined)